# Is it possible to have per-project users for standalone trac?

Tags: trac

I'm running a standalone tracd for multiple projects:

```
 tracd -p 8080 --basic-auth="*,/path/to/projects/.htpasswd, mycompany.com" -e /path/to/projects
```

The project environments are created under the */path/to/projects* and the users are added to */path/to/projects/.htpasswd*. This makes users to be shared across the projects, i.e. any user can access any project.

Is there any easy way to make per-project based user authentication using the standalone setup? I'm looking for a solution like this:

```
tracd -p 8080 --basic-auth="*,.htpasswd, mycompany.com" -e /path/to/projects
```

where the path of .htpasswd is relative to project enviroment, i.e. each environment has its own .htpasswd and the users are not crossed across the projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that you can use a different .htpasswd file per project to manage users in a single Trac install (when using Trac's internal web server).  I know that it is something that is being considered by the Trac community (see [Comprehensive Solution for Multiple Projects](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects/ComprehensiveSolution) for more information).

That being said, you do have the option of running Trac through Apache with Python to host multiple projects which opens the door a bit.  See [Multiple Projects in Trac through Apache](http://bitten.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects).  The short version is that in Apache, you'll do the following:

```
ScriptAlias /project /path/to/trac.cgi

<Location "/project">
    SetEnv TRAC_ENV "/path/to/trac/project"
</Location>

<Location "/project/login">
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "project - trac"
    AuthUserFile "/path/to/svn-auth-file"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

If you need to keep Trac as its own webserver, you can definitely set different permissions for different projects even when all Trac projects share the same .htpasswd file.  That way a user can be TRAC_ADMIN or WIKI_ADMIN of one Trac project while not having those permissions in a second Trac project.  You can do this from the command line using the trac-admin tool.  For example:

```
trac-admin /path/to/projenv permission add bob REPORT_DELETE
```

Or you can accomplish the same from the GUI (when logged in with a user with TRAC_ADMIN privileges to a specific project, go to Admin->Privileges).

For more on using the command line trac-admin tool for setting permissions (users and groups) see [Trac Permissions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions).  A more fine-tuned option for managing permissions using permission policies can be found at [Trac Permission Policies](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions).